# Best approach to identify if user paid for an app on google play

Tags: android, google-play

I seem to have reached dead-end as to how may i create a proper model which plays well under a scenario that i have in mind.

The scenario is as follows; User purchases an application from Google play. At run-time i request user credentials (Google account associated with current device) which i then transfer to a web-service. At that point the back-end service tries to Auth user and identify if they have actually purchased the application in question and only then return any data relative to the request. (keep in mind that any request in general, as we are talking about a content based application, to the web-service at any point of the run-time life-cycle must always pass through the above pipe).

Now the reason for the above scenario being so specific is for the following reason; 
-I would like everything to be managed by the end service rather than having any Auth process running natively as it may easily get bypassed. What i mean is that as long as anyone can decompile the application on their device, inspect the code, recompile it to their needs, have full access to any file if the device is rooted or even be allowed to clear any data related to the application by simply pressing the "clear data" option from android's application settings..... i do not see any other viable scenario other than the one i described above.

Now having said all of the above my problem is that it seems that Google does not like this specific scenario with  both Google play developer api and Google+ api.

So i would really appreciate your comments, thoughts and any related materials you may have to offer in regards to the scenario i mentioned and ways to tackle down this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any such API that you can use. Why not try LVL, which would make sure that it's actually downloaded from the Android market? And if it's a paid app, the user must have definitely paid for it.

As far as decompiling is concerned, try Proguard. It's not 100% perfect solution, but it's pretty hard to break it.

Now, coming to the content. If you don't want anyone else to steal your content, then encrypt and save it. You can have a pretty good encryption mechanism that works with your web services, which would ensure that it's very very difficult to break.

Comment: You are proposing a "trust the client" model which is well known to be far inferrior to the "don't trust the client" model the question seeks help in implementing.

Comment: I didn't propose any model. I am thinking about the workarounds that you can have. Moreover, you have to trust someone, somewhere, all the time. We all do it.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with using [LVL](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html) and [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html)? These tools were designed specifically to address your concerns with license verification and reverse engineering, respectively.

And, really don't worry too much about the one in a thousand people who might try to get your paid app for free. If your app is any good, then you'll be making plenty of sales anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If I've read your proposal correctly, that sounds like a gross violation of your users' privacy and would definitely be a violation of Google's ToS. Why would your users give you their private credentials? They aren't supposed to be given to anyone, so why should they trust you or your systems with them? You would also be liable if you got hacked and credentials were stolen.